# Getting the name of a Controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone application with a TabBarController. I can access the current ViewController with

```
[appDelegate.myTabBarController selectedViewController]
```

But how can I get the name of this controller?

For example the name of the selected ViewController is "TestViewController". How can I get this string/name?
I want to check if the current ViewController is "TestViewController".

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in this manner:

```
if([[appDelegate.myTabBarController selectedViewController] isKindOfClass:[TestViewController class]])
{
NSLog(@"Yes I am the controller you want.");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ([NSStringFromClass([[appDelegate.myTabBarController selectedViewController] class]) isEqualToString:@"TestViewController"])
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: You're comparing strings, so you should use `-[NSString isEqualToString:]`. But this is unnecessary. Just use `-[NSObject isKindOfClass:]`.

Comment: Sure, you're right, but I'm just giving the useful function NSStringFromClass() here

Comment: Agree with Francescu. It might be useful to compare the string (Name) of the class if you do not want to #import the class into the .h of the class that you're looking to make the comparison. I had a situation where I needed to figure which VC was being presented. So, I had some code that told me which the TopMostVC was. But in order to perform the isKindOfClass, I'd need to have the VC class in scope.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a subclass of UIViewController class and add property, for example

> ```
> @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
> ```

then make all of your viewControllers subclasses of the class with `name` property. then just set the name of the controller in your `-(id)init` or `-(void)viewDidLoad` method to be able to get access to it when you need.

the other way is to make some dictionary of class-name pairs. smth like this

> ```
> [myDictionary setValue:stringClassName forKey:[MyViewController class]];
> ```

make this dictionary available from all over the app - and you will be able to get name for each class  at any time you want if this class registered in your dictionary.